# quick recap by option clicking a method/class for libgdx framework

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Just created a first libgdx project and imported it into android studio. I am used to hovering over a method or a class and by option/alt clicking it, a little box shows up that tells me what this method/ class is good for. Is there a libgdx support for that kind of thing in android studio? It is a huuuge timesaver if you are a newbie like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS is based on IDEA, Ctrl+Q should work for Quick Documentation when cursor is inside method or class name. You can also Ctrl+LeftClick to go to source of the class or method.